# Why does my setLength/getLength and setWidth/getWidth not work

Tags: java, android, methods, compiler-errors

My setLength/getLength and setWidth/getWidth do not work. Apparently it's because it cannot find the symbol but I do not know what it means by this.

I tried everything it just seems not to work no matter how hard I try

```
    package practice;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Oval {

  private double width;
  private double length;

  public static void main(String[] args) {

  Oval oval = new Oval();
  oval.setLength(102.13);
  System.out.println("the circle's length is: " + oval.getLength());

  oval.setWidth(211.02);
  System.out.printf("The circle's width is: " + oval.getWidth());

  String str = "Given the length %, .4f and the width %, .4f,\n\t " + "the circle's     area is %,.4f sq.ft\n";
  System.out.printf(str, oval.getLength(), oval.getWidth, oval.getArea());
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see those methods implemented in the `Oval` class you posted. The only method you have posted is the `main()` method.

Comment: Sorry im new what do you mean by that?

Comment: @bruh those method don't work because you have to define them yourself, they are not automatically generated by the compiler.

Comment: I mean that you need to code those methods yourself, and you haven't done it as far as we can see. You really need to learn the basics of the language if you didn't know this, I suggest you read this before you keep writing code: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html. And also this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you need to create separate methods for the actual get/set methods, as you only have the main method. Perhaps you can do something outside of the main method, like this:

```
public double getLength(){
  return length;
}
public void setLength(double length){
  this.length = length;
}

public double getWidth(){
  return width;
}
public void setLength(double width){
  this.width = width;
}
```